# JQuery .post function is being ignored

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I currently have this code

```
$("button#Draw").click(function() {
            $.get( "test0test.php", {}, function( data ) {
            alert("WHY");
            });
            alert("WHY2");
            $.post( "test0test.php", {}, function( data ) {
            alert("WHY3");
            });
        });
```

and test0test.php has this code

```
<?php
echo "HELLO";
?>
```

I'm not even sure if that is relevant. My main issue is that the code in the function will not work. In this example, it is the alert("WHY"). The alert("WHY2") works perfectly fine. I've isolated the problem to it pretty much just ignoring the code.

Further background: I am currently using WAMP to test the code if that is somehow relevant. test0test.php is in the same folder as the html trying to access it as well.

Obviously what I was trying to do originally was not as simple as this but this code was the result of trying to figure out what the problem was. I'm at my wits end trying to figure as to why .get and .post do not work as this should be a simple thing...

The rest of my Javascript and jQuery work absolutely fine...

EDIT: I found out the reason... when testing it I should have used localhost instead of just right-clicking and opening the html files...

Comment: Add an error callback and see if your request is erroring out

Comment: Is that button in a form and the form is reloading the page?

Comment: Looks like your request is wrong. Maybe CORS, maybe incorrect php entry point setup... Need to see the error. Dev Tools Console and Network tab should help.

Comment: Looks like your server won't handle two near-simultaneous requests.

Comment: Nest the second request within the first and see what happens.